# To Log subsequent API calls (nested API calls) in a HTTP request using Serilog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-sinks-console

I'm working on to Log API request that went through multiple API for its response. Currently, I'm receiving the log of top level endpoint. I need to log all those subsequent log as HTTP request.

I've tried adding very own logging inside each API service. Instead, I would like a different, if I were about more APIs this would be more time consuming. I would like to have solutions, suggestion to log these kind of request more efficiently. SeriLog is my new field. So, all suggestions are welcomed !